# Getting "The connection attempt failed" error while connecting to postgres db usinng EMR jupyter notebook

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to connect to postgres database using Pyspark in EMR jupyter notebook but getting **"The connection attempt failed"** error

```
url = "jdbc:postgresql://your_postgresql_server:5432/database"

properties = {
    "user": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}
table_name = "table_name"

df = spark.read.jdbc(url, table_name, properties=properties)

df.show()
```

I have verified the credentials using dbeaver , everything looks good there.

Can someone suggest what might be the issue here?